# Error with Function Pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers

I am using this resource to help me out with Function Pointers: [here](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#defi) But in this code (written below), compilation on gcc says:

```
line 15: warning: dereferencing 'void*' pointer
line15:error:called object *foo is not a function
```

The code is here:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>

void print_mess(void *ptr)
{
        char *message = ptr;
        printf("%s\n",message);
}
void main()
{
        void* foo = print_mess;
        char *mess = "Hello World";
        (*foo)((void*)mess);
}
```

Very simple test function to brush up my knowledge, and I am embarassed to even encounter such a problem, let alone post it on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pointer is the wrong type. You need to use:

```
void (*foo)(void *) = print_mess;
```

It looks weird, but that's a function pointer definition. You can also typedef it:

```
typedef void (*vp_func)(void *);
vp_func foo = print_mess;
```

Comment: You mean vp_func = print_mess in the second line of the second code sample? What an idiot, I was to commit such a blunder!

Comment: @Soham, oops, forgot the variable name. But no, not quite :)